# Not displaying map within modal screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I cant seem to get my google map to display in my modal. The code is as follows. Does anyone see anything.

I just trying to get map to model window, no luck!

```
var mapOptions = {                                 
          zoom: 4,                                 
          center: centered,                        
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        };                                         
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maparea'), mapOptions;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({                         
position: loc,                                                
map: map,                                                     
title: $json.PDMOVE[x].SCNAME                                 
   });                                                        
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {  
infowindow.open(map, marker);                                 
   });                                                        
 });                                                          

$("#maparea").dialog({                           
  autoOpen:true,                                 
  modal: false,                                  
  title:'Empties',                               
  height: 550,                                   
  width: 700,                                    
  buttons: {                                     
      Close: function() {                        
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );              
      }                                          
     }                                           
});
```

Comment: i see javascript and no html. post all relevant code.

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net to demo your code.

Comment: Try ensuring that the #maparea div is visible before you initialize the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your target div is visible before map was init
is the modal you use have a success function ? so you can init map and i pretty sure it will work or you delay map init function by set timeout.